# ARP in Linux creates FAILED entries

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, arp

Under Linux-4.11 a locally generated ARP request would result in an ARP entry created with state FAILED (as seen by `ip neigh show`), when there's nobody to respond. Is this normal behaviour?

Also, flushing `sudo ip neigh flush dev eth0` doesn't flush the entries, they are still there.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

To flush Entries, you must root user
like as "sudo ip neigh flush dev eth0"

Comment: you can see more feature about arp at this question [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192313/clear-the-arp-cache-on-linux-really)